# Prevent VLC from starting a new instance every time a media file is opened

Tags: vlc

I'm using VLC. Its great for all media requirements. But I find this behavior annoying. Every time I open a media file, a sepearte VLC window opens up instead of stopping the current playback and play the new media. This applies to music as well as for videos. Could anyone help me in preventing it to open a new player window everytime I open a new media file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open Vlc, Go to **Tools** Menu -> Preferences-> Interface-> Instances->

Choose **Allow only one instance**